# ffmpeg scale2ref explanation?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm applying a watermark to a video. I'm trying to get the watermark to scale proportionally to the video dimensions. I've seen maybe a dozen different answers using scale2ref, but no explanations as to actually what's happening, so I'm finding it difficult to know how to implement/make changes to the configs to work for my situation.

Current overlay command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" output.mp4
```

Some answers I've looked at:

[ffmpeg creating gif from images, add watermark during creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359095/ffmpeg-creating-gif-from-images-add-watermark-during-creation)

[ffmpeg fix watermark size or percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513780/ffmpeg-fix-watermark-size-or-percentage/37514677#37514677)

What are the rules to how scale2ref works?

Comment: @gyan : Can you respond to this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Apply this filter to position the watermark

> Center:
>  overlay=(main_w-w)/2:(main_h-h)/2
> Top left corner:
>  overlay=1:1
> Top right corner:
>  overlay=W-w-1:1
> lower right corner:
>  overlay=W-w-1:H-h-1
> Bottom left corner:
>  overlay=1:H-h-1
> Bottom right corner. Padding 10px to the right and -10px to the bottom:
>  overlay=main_w-w/1:main_h-h/2
> Bottom right corner. Padding -10px to the right and -10px to the bottom:
>  overlay=main_w-w/1:main_h-h/2

Center:
-filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-w)/2:(main_h-h)/2" -preset ultrafast -codec:a copy